# Fixed effects and contrasts in MGCV with factor smooths

Tags: hypothesis-testing, interpretation, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, lsmeans

I was planning on running a Negative Binomial GAM as follows using various factor smooths:

$$
log(\mu_i)=s(D,by=Group)+s(Longitude,Latitude,by=Group)+x_0+x_1+x_2+Group+Treatment
$$

If I run a GAM  from MGCV using the above, I will get something like the following:

```
Family: Negative Binomial(3.803)
Link function: log

Formula:
counts ~ s(D, bs = "ps", k = ninters) + s(D, Group, bs = "fs") +
    s(Long, Lat, by = Group, k = ninters, bs = "ts") +
    x0 + x1 + x2 + Group + Treatment

Parametric coefficients:
                    Estimate    Std. Error t value             Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    -1597.8915095   409.2981675  -3.904         0.0000946277 ***
x0                0.1599002     0.0010605 150.778 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
x1                 0.0883601     0.0007244 121.972 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
x2               -0.0644919     0.0006716 -96.022 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
Group16     4.8829966     0.8976806   5.440         0.0000000534 ***
Group17    -1.1023817     1.0403389  -1.060                0.289
Group18   -21.8513728     1.5274532 -14.306 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
Group19  1504.6744947    88.3074157  17.039 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
Group20  -691.1758272    73.1617892  -9.447 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
Group21 -8304.5626719   850.8702080  -9.760 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
Treatment1              -0.0532320     0.0027507 -19.352 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
Treatment2               0.2413598     0.0193125  12.498 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                  edf Ref.df       F             p-value
s(D)                            36.55  36.91 16782.2 <0.0000000000000002 ***
s(D,Group)                  56.07  35.00   233.8              0.0776 .
s(Long,Lat):Group15 38.73  39.00   896.3 <0.0000000000000002 ***
s(Long,Lat):Group16 38.88  39.00   960.3 <0.0000000000000002 ***
s(Long,Lat):Group17 38.81  39.00   639.8 <0.0000000000000002 ***
s(Long,Lat):Group18 38.64  39.00   626.1 <0.0000000000000002 ***
s(Long,Lat):Group19 38.78  39.00   643.6 <0.0000000000000002 ***
s(Long,Lat):Group20 38.94  39.00   939.2 <0.0000000000000002 ***
s(Long,Lat):Group21 53.46  13.00  1766.5              1.0000
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.849   Deviance explained = 92.8%
fREML = 2.4018e+06  Scale est. = 1         n = 1640172
```

My primary question of interest in running this model is whether or not there is a difference between the treatment group levels rather than if a smooth is significant. I was planning on using emmeans to compute marginal means for the treatments and then test for differences between all pairwise treatment groups (0-1,1-2,0-2).

However, what has recently given me some pause though is the fact that penalized splines can be recast as a mixed model (I recall some difficulties with deriving valid p-values and interpreting fixed effects in the presence of random slopes for non-linear mixed models). In light of that, are the p-values still valid, and do the estimates for the fixed effects have a natural interpretation (IE Treatment 2 is associated with a $exp(0.24)=1.27$ multiplier for the expected counts).

As a follow up then, would it even make sense to compute the marginal means for each treatment group and then compute the differences between those groupings?

Comment: I don't see how this would be different from having any other covariate effects in the model. Note that you have just additive effects, so when you compare two treatments, all those spline effects cancel out.

Comment: @RussLenth I see, I hadn't considered what the actual contrast would eventually compute. Thanks for the response and your package!